# Compiling Error on LaTeX

Tags: pdflatex

I was trying to compile an article, so I could see the PDF version of it, but it appeared an error that says "Impossible to start the command. latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex". Does someone knows what this means? (This was supposed to be my first article in LaTeX. I'm using MilkTex and Tex Maker). Thank you.
(I've been looking for what it could be, and some say it is about path, but I don't understand what is that)

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
 \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\author{-------}
\title{xxxxxx}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

First adocument in LaTeX

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you post the code you compiled. Also, please visit [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I already put the code @M.AlJumaily , complete forget that!
I'll see that!

Comment: See, I did run your code and it worked like a charm. I Used Tex Maker 5.0.2 (latest version) to compile as PDFLatex, LaTeX and XeLatex which all worked. I suggest that you delete/uninstall all the Tex programs installed (i.e. MilkTex and Tex Maker) to start from scratch. Then, install proTeXt, [ProTeXt-3.1.9-121317.exe](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/windows/protext/) and then Tex Maker 5.0.2. proTeXt has many packages that are pre-installed and ready to use. It is about 2GB of packages... It highly might solve the problem.